# Getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while splitting

Tags: java, arrays, split

getting  `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` this error please help.

Following is the code

```
public void extractData(String stringToExtract)
{       
        String metaDataValue = stringToExtract;
        //System.out.println(metaDataValue);

        String [] splitMetaDataValue =  metaDataValue.split(",");
        String [] tokenValue = null;
        for (int i = 0; i<splitMetaDataValue.length ; i++)
        {
            tokenValue = splitMetaDataValue[i].split(":");
            System.out.println(tokenValue[0]+"->"+tokenValue[1]);
        }
}//extractData
```

Comment: Does your input contain any lines that don't have a colon?  If so, `tokenValue[1]` is going to be out of bounds.

Comment: yep.{"value":17,"validity":"3 Days","talktime":0},

Comment: Always check for null and then length before you do anything with the array that results fr a split operation. split actions fail silently so you wont get any errors unless you try to work up the resulting array.

Comment: Consider writing `System.out.println(splitMetaDataValue[i].replace(":","->"));` instead of using `split`.  It's probably safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When splitting something, it's always recommended to check the result.

Before you do:

```
tokenValue = splitMetaDataValue[i].split(":");
```

Check the length of `splitMetaDataValue`.

Answer (score 1):

`splitMetaDataValue[i].split(":").length` has to be 2 in order for the following to work:

> System.out.println(tokenValue[0]+"->"+tokenValue[1]);

i.e.

```
tokenValue = splitMetaDataValue[i].split(":");

if (tokenValue.length > 1) {
    System.out.println(tokenValue[0]+"->"+tokenValue[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the size of String[] tokenValue.
The lines

```
System.out.println(tokenValue[0]+"->"+tokenValue[1]);
```

must be causing ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception because they are assumptions that splitMetaDataValue[i] will contain ":".

Answer (score 0):

The expression `splitMetaDataValue[i].split(":")` is not guaranteed to yield an array of 2 `Strings` - check the array length before attempting to access its elements

```
if (tokenValue.length >= 2) {
  System.out.println(tokenValue[0]+"->"+tokenValue[1]);
}
```